# PostgreSQL How find completely identical orders on set of items and their quantity?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, identity, sqlite3-python

I have a table with orders (for each order (transaction_id) there are client_id and item_id and quantity)
I need to find completely identical orders for a set of goods and their quantity in the order

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (client_id varchar(10),
            item_id varchar(10), quantity int, transaction_id varchar(10));
INSERT INTO orders values 
        ('CL1111','111',1, '1001'),
        ('CL1111','222',2,'1001'),
        ('CL1111','333',1,'1001'),
        ('CL2222','111',2,'1002'),
        ('CL2222','222',1,'1002'),
        ('CL2222','333',1,'1002'),
        ('CL3333','111',1,'1003'),
        ('CL3333','222',2,'1003'),
        ('CL3333','333',1,'1003'),
        ('CL3333','444',1,'1003'),
        ('CL4444','111',1,'1004'),
        ('CL4444','222',2,'1004'),
        ('CL4444','333',1,'1004'),
        ('CL5555','111',1,'1005'),
        ('CL5555','222',2,'1005'),
        ('CL6666','111',1,'1006'),
        ('CL6666','222',2,'1006'),
        ('CL6666','333',1,'1007')
```

| client_id | item_id | quantity | transaction_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CL1111 | 111 | 1 | 1001 |
| CL1111 | 222 | 2 | 1001 |
| CL1111 | 333 | 1 | 1001 |
| CL2222 | 111 | 2 | 1002 |
| CL2222 | 222 | 1 | 1002 |
| CL2222 | 333 | 1 | 1002 |
| CL3333 | 111 | 1 | 1003 |
| CL3333 | 222 | 2 | 1003 |
| CL3333 | 333 | 1 | 1003 |
| CL3333 | 444 | 1 | 1003 |
| CL4444 | 111 | 1 | 1004 |
| CL4444 | 222 | 2 | 1004 |
| CL4444 | 333 | 1 | 1004 |
| CL5555 | 111 | 1 | 1005 |
| CL5555 | 222 | 2 | 1005 |
| CL6666 | 111 | 1 | 1006 |
| CL6666 | 222 | 2 | 1006 |
| CL6666 | 333 | 1 | 1007 |

Identical orders here are: (1001 and 1004), (1005 and 1006)
And now I don't know, how to leave orders, which completely identical on item_id, quantity and set of items.

Comment: picture is not available. Please share the information in plain text.

Comment: all the solutions presented below helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query. Order clause in aggregation is necessary for reliable result.

```
with transactions as(
select client_id,transaction_id
   ,string_agg( (item_id ||'('||cast(quantity as varchar) || ')') ,',' order by item_id) itemlist
from orders
group by client_id,transaction_id
)
select * 
  ,row_number()over(partition by itemlist order by client_id,transaction_id) rn
  ,count(*)over(partition by itemlist) cnt
from transactions
order by itemlist
```

Rows with cnt>1 is has identical row (identical items with same quantity).

With test data, find 2 identical groups for transaction_id 1001-1004 and 1005-1006 (not green in your picture)

result is

| client_id | transaction_id | itemlist | rn | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CL5555 | 1005 | 111(1),222(2) | 1 | 2 |
| CL6666 | 1006 | 111(1),222(2) | 2 | 2 |
| CL1111 | 1001 | 111(1),222(2),333(1) | 1 | 2 |
| CL4444 | 1004 | 111(1),222(2),333(1) | 2 | 2 |
| CL3333 | 1003 | 111(1),222(2),333(1),444(1) | 1 | 1 |
| CL2222 | 1002 | 111(2),222(1),333(1) | 1 | 1 |
| CL6666 | 1007 | 333(1) | 1 | 1 |

Test data

```
INSERT INTO orders (client_id,item_id,transaction_id,quantity)
values 
        ('CL1111','111','1001',1),
        ('CL1111','222','1001',2),
        ('CL1111','333','1001',1),
        ('CL2222','111','1002',2),
        ('CL2222','222','1002',1),
        ('CL2222','333','1002',1),
        ('CL3333','111','1003',1),
        ('CL3333','222','1003',2),
        ('CL3333','333','1003',1),
        ('CL3333','444','1003',1),
        ('CL4444','111','1004',1),
        ('CL4444','222','1004',2),
        ('CL4444','333','1004',1),
        ('CL5555','111','1005',1),
        ('CL5555','222','1005',2),
        ('CL6666','111','1006',1),
        ('CL6666','222','1006',2),
        ('CL6666','333','1007',1)
;
```

Comment: oh, yes, I didn't note 1005-1006. Yes , You helped me to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your example code doesn't include quantity!
Here is a code that results as many rows as the table contains the same orders:

```
sql = """
    with orders_mod as
    (
        select distinct
                "transaction_id",
                string_agg("item_id" || ' ' || "quantity"::text, ',') over (partition by "client_id") as "list_of_ordered_item_ids"
        from    orders
    )
    select distinct
            string_agg("transaction_id", ',') over (partition by "list_of_ordered_item_ids") as "list_of_the_same_orders",
            "list_of_ordered_item_ids"
    from    orders_mod
    ;
"""

df_SQL = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
df_SQL
```

Comment: Thank You very much - this is the most helpful decision of my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query, it returns correct rows in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QbTGxPSI)

```
with agg as (
  SELECT client_id, 
         array_agg(array[item_id]) ai, array_agg(array[quantity]) aq
  from orders group by client_id 
  having count(distinct transaction_id) = 1 )
select client_id, ai items, aq quantities 
from (
  select client_id, ai , aq , count(1) over (partition by ai, aq) cnt
  from agg ) c
where cnt > 1
```

| client_id | items | quantities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CL1111 | {{111},{222},{333}} | {{1},{2},{1}} |
| CL4444 | {{111},{222},{333}} | {{1},{2},{1}} |

I am not sure what about clients having several transactions, but in your examples clients CL5555 and CL6666 are not matched even though they have same transactions 1005 and 1006. So here only clients having one distinct transaction are compared.

Comment: Thank You @Ponder Stibbons! I think I didn't explain correct, but this solving, based on your code helped me:
```select
  transaction_id
from
  (
  select
       transaction_id, 
       ai,
       aq,
       count(1) over (partition by ai, aq) cnt
  from
       (
       select
            transaction_id, 
            array_agg(array[item_id]) ai, 
            array_agg(array[quantity]) aq
       from orders 
       group by transaction_id 
       ) a
  ) a
where cnt > 1```

Comment: So post your query as answer and accept it :) Maybe this will help someone in the future. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
     transaction_id
from
     (
     select
        transaction_id,
        ai,
        aq,
        count(1) over (partition by ai, aq) cnt
     from
          (
          select
               transaction_id,
               array_agg(array[item_id]) ai,
               array_agg(array[quantity]) aq
          from orders
          group by transaction_id
          ) a
     ) a
where cnt > 1
```